# How do I add projection information to this JPG and convert to geoTIFF in GDAL?

Tags: gdal, satellite

I have a .jpg image (weather satellite) that needs to have projection information applied to it and converted to geoTIFF in EPSG:3857, but due to the complexity of the projection I have no idea where to start using GDAL.

The .jpg (image.jpg) can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ajta9fE0w97OuVr0gx7jzQ5nhsqWpvHn/view?usp=sharing) for reference, if it matters.

The projection of the image should be the following (taken from a netCDF file of the same data) geostationary projection:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Spheroid",6378137,298.2572221]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Geostationary_Satellite"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],
    PARAMETER["satellite_height",35786023],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=geos +lon_0=-75 +h=35786023 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs  +sweep=x"]]
```

I have tried about 50 combinations of scripts using gdalwarp and even though I like to show effort instead of blatantly asking for help, doing so would only clutter my question. I am pretty lost.

Is this possible to do, or do I need more information than the gdalinfo I pasted above?

Edit: I also know what the bounding box should be : (after being reprojected to EPSG:3857)

```
West    -151.8860639
North    56.77489167
East    -52.91295 
South    14.56403889
```

Edit 2: This is a netCDF file that has the same projection needed for the .jpg : [https://s3.amazonaws.com/noaa-goes16/ABI-L1b-RadC/2020/211/05/OR_ABI-L1b-RadC-M6C13_G16_s20202110526162_e20202110528547_c20202110529074.nc](https://s3.amazonaws.com/noaa-goes16/ABI-L1b-RadC/2020/211/05/OR_ABI-L1b-RadC-M6C13_G16_s20202110526162_e20202110528547_c20202110529074.nc%0A)

Comment: could you not convert the netCDF file directly to a GeoTiff?

Comment: I can't. The image information in the JPG images vs the netCDF are actually different, but the projection is the same.The JPG is a derived product from the satellite .nc files, and so .nc files don't exist for them. This is why I can still use any of the .nc files to atleast see the projection I need. I have added a link to my question. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Hi David, don't do that. Use the raw data, try to investigate how is the image composed and create your own images. I am developing some scripts to compose images from goes-16 data, what is the page explaining that image?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca The page with the images is https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/goes/conus.php?sat=G16. I would like to project all of them to 3857 somehow. (There is also a small back band on the bottom of the imagery. I can use imagemagick to mask this, or to remove it if needed).

Comment: The GeoColor is the harder to derive image. This is the research : https://journals.ametsoc.org/jtech/article/37/3/429/345394/GeoColor-A-Blending-Technique-for-Satellite, others (georeferenced) can be downloaded from http://home.chpc.utah.edu/~u0553130/Brian_Blaylock/cgi-bin/goes16_download.cgi

Comment: I actually have found a way to do this. First. I downloaded a full disk .nc file and converted to .TIF. Then, I grabbed the geocolor full disk from the link and converted it to TIF. Last, I used a tool called "gdalcopyproj" and copied the projection from the first TIF to the 2nd. However, this only works on the 5424x5424 resolution files, and not the 10848x10848 files. So I am trying to figure this out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That bounding box can't be the bounding box of the rectangular image because it looks like the edge of the planet in the top left. That means the corner coordinates are outside any lat-long space. Maybe your "West" limit is the latitude of the curved edge of the earth.

If you have the bounding box *in the projected coordinate system* - ie metres in that geostationary satellite CRS - then its doable analytically, otherwise you can do georeferencing via matching control points. You could use georeferencing to estimate the source bounding box and then do an analytic transformation with `gdalwarp`

So yes, I think you do need extra information, namely the bounding box in the source coordinates, not lat-long. If you have a NetCDF with the same coordinate system and bounding box then you might be able to get it from that.

One of the NetCDF layers, loaded into QGIS, shows its bounding box corners in the geostationary coordinate system:

```
Extent  -3627271.3409673548303545,1583173.7916531809605658 : 
1382771.9477514973841608,4589199.7648844923824072
```

and its 2500 by 1500 pixels, giving a pixel width and height of 2004.017 units. The jpg is 5000 by 3000 pixels so its pixel size if half that.

If you create a "World File" called `lights.jpgw` in the same folder as the `lights.jpg` image, then that will spatially register the image. You can calculate this or use something like QGIS to export one of the NetCDF layer info as a World File and then halve the pixel size, giving:

```
1002.0085
0.00000000
0.00000000
-1002.0085
-3626269.33234224
4588197.75624227
```

That locates the image. Next create `src.prj` with the projection text in it, namely:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Spheroid",6378137,298.2572221]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Geostationary_Satellite"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],
    PARAMETER["satellite_height",35786023],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=geos +lon_0=-75 +h=35786023 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs  +sweep=x"]]
```

Now `gdalwarp` has all the info it needs. Do:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs srs.prj -t_srs epsg:3857 lights.jpg light_merc.tif
```

to create an EPSG 3857 (Web mercator) reprojection. It will throw up some errors because the top left corner doesn't project into the earth, and it will be distorted and hence not accurate at the edges. But I get this:

[image]

Which looks pretty good. Zoomed in a bit with an overlay setting in QGIS so you can see both gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I know that the bounding box is on the surface of the earth after the netCDF is reprojected to EPSG:3857. All of the netCDF files have the same projection, as well as the images that I am trying to copy the projection to. I do in fact have a source file sample. Here is a direct link to a netCDF on the Amazon AWS server -https://s3.amazonaws.com/noaa-goes16/ABI-L1b-RadC/2020/211/05/OR_ABI-L1b-RadC-M6C13_G16_s20202110526162_e20202110528547_c20202110529074.nc. I need that same projection applied to the JPG.

Comment: I have seen your edited answer, but when I try to use gdal_translate as you have, it fails with "ERROR 1: buildCS: missing UNIT". Any idea? Also, should I be naming the .prj file "lights.prj" or "srs.prj"? I have tried both.

Comment: The file name can be anything, its only used in the `gdalwarp` command line to be explicit about what the source CRS is. I don't get the ERROR 1: though, since there's clearly a UNIT spec in the projection file. `gdalwarp --version` gives me GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is also having the "buildCS: missing UNIT" issue mentioned in the comments above, add UNIT to the GOES16 src.prj:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Spheroid",6378137,298.2572221]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Geostationary_Satellite"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],
    PARAMETER["satellite_height",35786023],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=geos +lon_0=-75 +h=35786023 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +sweep=x"]]
```

gdal version 3.3.1 over here.